# Application of Law of Total Expectation

Tags: probability

> Let $(Xn)_{n≥0}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables with positive mean $\mu$ defined on $(Ω, F, \mathbb{P})$
>   Define $S_0 = 0,Sn =\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $τ = \inf\{n ≥ 1 : Xn = a\}$ for $a ∈ \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\mathbb{E}(S_\tau)=\mu\cdot\mathbb{E}(\tau)$

This seems intuitively correct, but I am having difficulties finding the proof. $\tau$ can be interpreted as the first time we hit $a$. By the Law of Total Expectation we have:
$E[S_\tau]=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(S_k|\tau=k)\mathbb{P}(\tau=k)$, but I am not sure how this is going to help me finding the correct proof. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Is $\mathbb P(X_1=a)>0$? If not then $\tau\notin\mathbb R$ a.s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, that we have by the law of total expectation
\begin{align*}
  \def\P{\mathbf P}\def\E{\mathbf E}
  \E[S_\tau] &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \E[S_\tau \mid \tau = k]\P(\tau = k)\\
             &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \E[S_k]\P(\tau = k)\\
             &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k\mu\P(\tau = k)\\
             &= \mu \sum_{k=0}^\infty k\P(\tau = k)\\
             &= \mu\E[\tau]. 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

$\tau$ is defined as the index such that $X_\tau=a, ~\forall k{\in}\{1..\tau{-}1\}\big[~X_k\neq a~\big]$.

Then $\tau$ is geometrically distributed $\tau\sim\mathcal{Geo}_1(p)$, where $p$ is the (presumably non-zero) probability that specific arbitrary random variable is $a$.

$$\forall k\geq 1~\Big[\mathsf P(X_k{=}a)=p\Big]$$

$$\mathsf E(\tau)=\tfrac 1 p$$

The expected value of the $X_\tau$ is naturally $a$, where as the expected value of all prior $X_k$ is *not* $\mu$, but *rather* $\frac{\mu-ap}{1-p}$

$$\mathsf E(X_\tau)~=~a\\\mathsf E(X_k\mid k<\tau)~=~\frac{\mu-a~p}{1-p}$$

So using the Law of Iterated Expectation.

$\begin{align}\mathsf E(S_\tau) ~ = & ~ \mathsf E\Big(\mathsf E(S_\tau\mid \tau)\Big)\\ ~ = & ~ \mathsf E\Big(\mathsf E\big(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\tau X_k\mid \tau\big)\Big) \\ ~ = & ~ \mathsf E\Big(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\tau-1}\big(\frac{\mu-a~p}{1-p}\big)+a\Big) \\ ~ = & ~ (\mathsf E(\tau)-1)(\frac{\mu-ap}{1-p})+a \\ ~ = & ~ (\tfrac 1 p-1)(\frac{\mu-ap}{1-p})+a\\ ~ = & ~ \frac \mu p
\\[3ex]\mathsf E(S_\tau) ~ = & ~ \mu~\mathsf E(\tau)\end{align}$